# Is deleting all partitions on USB is safe?

Tags: usb, malware, malware-detection, usb-flash-drive

I have an infected USB flash drive. So I used gparted live to safely remove all partitions and created an NTFS one before inserting in windows. But I'm really worries if any malware in raw data can infect my computer somehow. Is it really possible?

I formatted all partitions so raw data remains.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's possible even if there are no partitions. For example if you read the raw data, create an executable file and run it. But I'm not sure windows do that when you just insert an usb

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).